# Dell PowerEdge R330 and an MD1400

Tags: raid, configuration

I have an R330 with an H830 to connect the MD1400.....2 OS drives are the 1.8 SSD's leaving the 4x 3.5" bays available.  Once I connect the MD1400, could I include any R330 hard drives added and MD1400 hard drives into a single array, or would I have to consider the R330 drives their own array and the MD1400 as a separate array?

Comment: They would be separate arrays. One array would be managed by the servers own RAID controller and the other array would be managed by the RAID controller in the MD1400.

Comment: @joeqwerty hi :) if you write that as an answer I would upvote, was about to write the same thing, lol :)

Answer (score 1):

They would be separate arrays. One array would be managed by the servers own RAID controller and the other array would be managed by the RAID controller in the MD1400.